# How do I tell render the location of the views partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `sessions/new.html.erb` for users to sign_in and `users/new.html.erb` for users to sign_up. I want to put both of the forms in those files on the same page rather than having 2 different screens: one for login and another for sign up. 
I do not know how to render 2 different files in 2 different folders though.

How do I render these?

Comment: After you have read the documentation for rendering partials (e.g. [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), what have you found and what are your questions based on this documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial can do

Rename your *sessions/new.html.erb* to sessions/_new.html.erb

Rename your *users/new.html.erb* to users/_new.html.erb

You can render partials in a view like this

```
<div class='session-form'>
<%= render partial: 'sessions/new' %>
</div>
<div class='login-form'>
<%= render partial: 'users/new' %>
</div>
```

For more options and information: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Hope it could help! :)

Comment: Did you meant `users/new.html.erb` *to* `users/_new.html.erb` ?

Comment: yup, updated. I markdown the filename to italic with '_' so it broke.